# Merging/downsizing RFID cards somehow

Tags: rfid

I have 3-4 RFID cards in my wallet, and they all work just fine when I press my wallet against the card readers - despite being 4-5 cards deep in my wallet.

I want the benefit of having these cards in my wallet, but in a smaller form factor.

Does something exist that can make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. [Emulate the cards.](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1980078555/chameleonmini-a-versatile-nfc-card-emulator-and-mo) It's possible to build a device that responds with different IDs. This shouldn't work for "secure" cards like contactless payment, but for simple access systems it will work.
2. Dissolve the cards. They're usually made of acrylic, so you can melt away the plastic leaving you with a chip and a very fragile coil of wire. These can then be incorporated into another object.

Comment: This ChameleonMini is an interesting find. I think it requires quite a bit of knowledge of the technology and the actual structure of the cards to make it work, though. Also, I believe the card plastic is typically PVC, not acrylic.